# Mounting a ConfigMap as a volume in Kubernetes: how do I calculate the value of defaultMode?

Tags: kubernetes

Defining the **defaultMode** in a Kubernetes **volume** field within a **deployment** element can become quite tricky.

It expects three decimals, corresponding to the binary UNIX permissions.

As an example, to mount the ConfigMap with permissions r------, you'd need to specify 256.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: foo
  namespace: foo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: foo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: foo
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: php-fpm:latest
          volumeMounts:
            - name: phpini
              mountPath: /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/99-settings.ini
              readOnly: true
              subPath: 99-settings.ini
      volumes:
        - configMap:
            defaultMode: 256
            name: phpini-configmap
            optional: false
          name: phpini
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    app: foo
  namespace: foo
  name: phpini-configmap
data:
  99-settings.ini: |
    ; Enable Zend OPcache extension module
    zend_extension = opcache
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the following table:

| unix octal | unix readable | binary equivalent | decimal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0400 | r-------- | 100000000 | 256 |
| 0440 | r--r----- | 100100000 | 288 |
| 0444 | r--r--r-- | 100100100 | 292 |
| 0600 | rw------- | 110000000 | 384 |
| 0600 | rw-r----- | 110100000 | 416 |
| 0660 | rw-rw---- | 110110000 | 432 |
| 0660 | rw-rw-r-- | 110110100 | 436 |
| 0666 | rw-rw-rw- | 110110110 | 438 |
| 0700 | rwx------ | 111000000 | 448 |
| 0770 | rwxrwx--- | 111111000 | 504 |
| 0777 | rwxrwxrwx | 111111111 | 511 |

A more direct way to do this is to use a base8 to base10 converter like [this one](http://www.unitconversion.org/numbers/base-8-to-base-10-conversion.html)

Help from https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/config-and-storage-resources/volume/#projections

> defaultMode is optional: mode bits used to set permissions on created
> files by default. Must be an octal value between 0000 and 0777 or a
> decimal value between 0 and 511. YAML accepts both octal and decimal
> values, JSON requires decimal values for mode bits. Defaults to 0644.
> Directories within the path are not affected by this setting. This
> might be in conflict with other options that affect the file mode,
> like fsGroup, and the result can be other mode bits set.

Answer (score 0):

Misleading: the first column is NOT "unix decimal" but simply "octal".

Please fix your table! Decimal is what you show in the "defaultMode" column.

You can have other flags (e.g. "s" and "t") with higher numerical values and still use them with octal values. Unix/Linux command-line tools never use any "decimal" numeric value for file access rights, always "octal" (with digits '0'-'7'), or "symbolic" (with letters and '+'/'-' signs). Digits 8 and 9 are never used in those Unix/Linux tools.

But Kubernetes config files actually use integers (that you must write in decimal by default). These config files are written using the "YAML" syntax, which only supports decimal syntaxes.